# Someone familiar with Netbeans: Why does this happen? Error isn't really an error?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

When writing something simple like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please enter array size: ");
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int [] anArray;
        int index = 100;
        anArray = new int[x];
        for (int i=0; i<=x; i++){
            anArray[i] = index;
            index += 100;
            System.out.println ("Element at index "+ i + ": " + anArray[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Netbeans compiles and runs the code properly but the output ends up looking like this:

```
run:
Please enter array size: 
12
Element at index 0: 100
Element at index 1: 200
Element at index 2: 300
Element at index 3: 400
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
Element at index 4: 500
Element at index 5: 600
Element at index 6: 700
Element at index 7: 800
Element at index 8: 900
Element at index 9: 1000
Element at index 10: 1100
Element at index 11: 1200
   at Practice.main(Practice.java:21)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Which seems off to me.. why is the exception thrown halfway through the code? and then finished at the end?

And it points to line 21:
    anArray[i] = index;

Honestly not a big issue.. i'm just playing around and reviewing some basics of Java (it's been a while...) and the exception is making me feel like I'm doing something wrong but then I'm not sure I actually am because it seems to be working how I intended.

Thank you!

Comment: The problem deals more with sychronisation of the threads then it does with your code.  Netbeans is probably monitoring the stderr and stdin using two different threads and then it is trying to synchronise the output into a single thread (the EDT), but because each line is (probably) synchronized separately, they overlap.  Yes, it's annoying.  One might argue that having two separate windows would be more helpful and sometimes it would and sometimes it wouldn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the for statement:

```
for (int i=0; i<x; i++){ // Change <= to <
        anArray[i] = index;
        index += 100;
        System.out.println ("Element at index "+ i + ": " + anArray[i]);
    }
```

If you create an array with `length = 12`, then you can access it by:

```
anArray[0]
anArray[1]
...
anArray[11]
```

But you are accessing it up to `anArray[12]`, so it throws the error.

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense now that you point it out! Any idea why it throws the exception on two different lines in the output like that?

Comment: Being sincere, I don't know. But the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` errors are easy to detect because the trace error tells you what `bad` index you tried to access, in your case `12`: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12`